# How to control a Media Player with C#?

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

I searched a little, but I have found a lot of old results, so I decided to ask here.

I want to control a Media Player playlist. I don't want to create a form with media controllers.

I want to open my media player and let a windows application control the playlist. 
Based on a music list I want to do a few operations like play/pause/stop and insert a track in a specific position of the playlist. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Windows Media Player SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There's a specific section for [Playlists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) too.